# Weblogic OSB 2-way SSL connection

Tags: ssl, weblogic, keystore, osb

I have an OSB service which communicates with a bank by 2way SSL connection. OSB_server configured to use "*Custom Identity and Java Standard Trust keystores*". Identity keystore has server certificate and trust keystore CA certificates. Private alias set to use "key" -
Ive added client sertificate received by bank to identity keystore, CA to "cacerts" and changed SSL private alias to received one "800345" and set UseServerCerts to true.
Communication with bank working fine, but.. other services doesn't work because of wrong private SSL certificate.

Found solution where I can use WLST scripting to change private key, but it requires restart or module redeploy.
Another solution found was with PKI provider/credential mapping. In weblogic noted that this is deprecated technology, but anyway tried it... received exception that my created provider didn't find in weblogic home domain (it is there).

In general I have:

- key pair from Bank CA cert from Bank

Could you please help with this? Where I should insert this keys to make OSB service working? Any other solution would be nice to hear.. or any tutorials..

Comment: What error are you getting? It's hard to tell what the question is...

Comment: Salut, @better_use_mkstemp


"Could not create a JKS keystore instance for provider KeyStoreProvider. Exception: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: KeyStoreProvider"


names for my providers:

KeyStoreProvider with identity/trust keystores stored in $HOME_DOMAIN directory

KeyStoreCredentialMapping with KeyStoreProvider FileName and identity store in $HOME_DOMAIN..

I think that config is false for KeyStoreCredentialMapping.. maybe could you please provide any example?